# Transferir campos de uma tabela para outra

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom dia, existe alguma maneira de transferir os campos a mais de uma tabela para outra?

Eu tenho um banco de dados desatualizado e preciso criar os campos novos em várias tabelas.
Existe alguma query que faça isso, uso firebird 2.1 com o IBExpert

Exemplo

Eu tenho 2 tabelas, e umas delas tem campos novos e adicionar os campos na tabela do outro banco de dados. E tenho que fazer isso com todas as tabelas para ficarem os bancos de dados com as tabelas atualizadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mostre sua estrutura e o que quer fazer, dê um exemplo

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta com um exemplo.

Comment: você deveria ter o script da atualização da base. Não há um comando específico para atualizar uma base comparando-a com outra. Há softwares de terceiros que podem fazer isso, mas normalmente pagos além de que, pode ter problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O IBExpert possui o recurso de comparação das base de dados(Menu Tools, Database Comparer), que compara as duas base de dados e gera um script com as mudanças necessárias. Ao executar este script na base de dados alvo, você estará copiando a estrutura.
Existem outras ferramentas que realizam a comparação e geram os DDL necessários, acesse: https://www.firebase.com.br/downloads.php?categ=4.

Tenho por pratica copiar para um arquivo de script todos os DDL executados em desenvolvimento, assim tenho o script necessário a atualização de todos os banco de dados em produção.